# when trying to upload same image consecutive times in markdown editor first time it is getting uploaded but second time it is not getting uploaded

Tags: javascript

If i try to upload two different images consecutive times then it is working fine.
Here is the Markdown editor configuration:

```
$('#Document_editor').markdownEditor({            
            imageUpload: true,
            uploadPath: '/Package/UploadImage/?height=' + 10 + "&width=" + 10,
            preview: true,
            theme: "tomorrow",
            fullscreen: false,
            onPreview: function (content, callback) {
                var converter = new showdown.Converter();
                var result = converter.makeHtml(content);
                callback(result);
            }
        });
```